# Regrading STL Map checking for entry using find

Tags: c++, stl

I am following program

```
typedef std::map<std::string, CRTSLogManager*> FileNameToStorageClass;
FileNameToStorageClass  m_mapFileNameToLogStorage;
map<string, void*>::iterator iter;
iter =m_mapFileNameToLogStorage.find(cFileName);

if(iter == m_mapFileNameToLogStorage.end())
{
   typedef std::pair<std::string, CRTSLogManager*> FileNameToStorageClassPair;
   string strFilename = "MyFile";
   CRTSLogManager *pLogManager = new CRTSLogManager();
   m_mapFileNameToLogStorage.insert(
      FileNameToStorageClassPair(strFilename, pLogManager));
}
```

I am getting following error while compiling which is related to == check in if condition.

> no match for 'operator==' in 'iter ==
>   ((CRTSLogManagerReal*)this)->CRTSLogManagerReal::m_mapFileNameToLogStorage.std::map,
>   std::allocator >,
>   CRTSLogManager*,
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > >,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::allocator >,
>   CRTSLogManager*> >::.std::_Tree<_Traits>::end
>   with _Traits =
>   std::_Tmap_traits,
>   std::allocator >,
>   CRTSLogManager*,
>   std::less,
>   std::allocator > >,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::allocator >,
>   CRTSLogManager*> >, false>'

Comment: You might want to format that a bit better using the "code sample" option.

Comment: There's also a few syntax errors, e.g. the typedef misses template parameters for map, which make this code hard to try out on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring an iterator for a

```
std::map <string, void *>
```

but you are trying to compare against an iterator for a

```
std::map< std::string, CRTSLogManager*>
```

They are not compatible.

Comment: Well spotted, I'd assumed that was just an oversight in missing std:: out!

Comment: It's not the std:: on string that is the issue but that void is not the same type as CRTSLogManager

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't iter be declared as

```
FileNameToStorageClass::iterator iter;
```

?

Answer (score 2):

`std::map<std::string, CRTSLogManager*>` and `map<string, void*>` are different types and do not have the same iterator type, so you cannot compare two instances of those iterators. If you're going to use typedefs, you should use them consistently:

```
FileNameToStorageClass::iterator iter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing a typename arguments for templatized class like std::map?

What is the class or data type for your key/value pair?
Seems like you want std::string for your key and pointer to CRTSLogManager object as the value.

In that case, your typedef alias FileNameToStorageClass should probably be:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, CRTSLogManager*> FileNameToStorageClass;
```

However, the code you posted does not seem to be a working program at all.
For example, this line:

```
string strFilename = "MyFile"
```

won't work unless you defined your own class "string" or have std namespace loaded. I am assuming you are using std::string.